# Owl ontology in protege

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege, linked-data

I want to create an ontology based on a MeSH RDF descriptor for example pancreas (https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D010179.html). So far i have created a class using that URI hence its name is D010179. Regarding its properties, how do i form them and how do i connect the descriptor to these properties? For example, i know that allowableQualifier(http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#allowableQualifier) is an objectProperty but i can't connect it to D010179 since that's a class and object properties only can only link individuals. To overcome that problem i have used allowableQualifier as an annotation property but i don't know if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the work MeSH has already done?

Comment: @jayGray yes i have but i was trying to do it on my own, kinda like a challenge so i can get better at this. I've managed to do it using only annotation properties even though i know this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: my advice: start with MeSH (authority version) and experiment from that point.